# Pressing a button programmatically in webview/webkit

Tags: android, ios, webview

Does anyone know a way to programmatically press a button in webkit/webview?

Comment: how do you determine when the buttons should be "Click" . and what is the point of programmatically clicking a button

Comment: They should be clicked to avoid the api usage of an external website

Comment: Yes, I believe you can execute JavaScript code in WebView.